# Find "?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"

Tags: android

I am setting some default `styles` for my app, and I wanted to have the `?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium` as a parent of a `style`...but I can't, Android Studio complains about that reference, so I have to instead make the parent as `parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"`.

The problem is that `@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"` isn't getting me the same `text color` as `?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium`does, so I wonder **how to find the correct style pointed by `?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium`?**

Answer (score 1):

Your app theme should extend one of the framework themes or a theme in one of your dependencies (e.g. AppCompat). You can navigate to a the parent theme in Android Studio the same way you can jump to a method's implementation (for me it's `command` + click).

The value of `?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium` depends on the current theme, so you might have to do this for each theme you declare. Also be aware that the style can differ depending on which API level you are running on, so you might have to do the same.

**EDIT**

Since you are interested in affecting the text color, as an alternative you might consider setting a value for `android:textColorPrimary` and `android:textColorSecondary` in your theme.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to follow AppCompat, but I couldn't find the text color anywhere, much more the less the Medium text style.... That's why I was asking, because I can't find it...

Comment: I know I can set the colors, but I wanted to get them so I can set them....of course I can just set some random colors that look close to them, but then I didn't learn anything from it and if I need another style in the future I am helpless because I don't know how to search for it....so my purpose in this question is to really learn how to fetch that properties

Comment: @mFeinstein I don't really know how else to help you. I am able to traverse the parent styles all the way back to the base Android themes defined by the framework (i.e. past all the AppCompat ones). You just have to keep going until you reach one which declares a value for that attribute. It's going to be a style reference, that style might be in AppCompat or it might be in the Android framework, but in either case I am still able to step into them.

Comment: I have an emulator with android 6, the text color is dark gray for the theme, if I use the style it becomes black, can you find that Grey and tell me where it is?